# Correct way of initializing a unique_ptr

Tags: c++11

Working on learning how to use smart pointers and C++ in general... Assume that I have the following class:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(const T& def_val)
private:
  std::unique_ptr<T> default_val;
};
```

What is the idiomatic way of implementing the constructor if I would only like to store a pointer to an object of type T with the value given in the default_val class member? My understanding is also that I don't have to define a destructor at all, since the unique_ptr will automatically taking care of cleaning up itself?

Comment: `unique_ptr<T>` owns a pointer to a dynamically-allocated `T` ... so you need to dynamically-allocate a `T` and store it in `default_val`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have written your code, MyClass can only store a unique pointer to a *copy* of the constructor parameter:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const T& def_val)
: default_val(new T(def_val))
{
}
```

This means that T must be copy constructible.

> My understanding is also that I don't have to define a destructor at all, since the unique_ptr will automatically taking care of cleaning up itself?

Correct. That is 1 of 2 main purposes for `unique_ptr`, the 2nd being the guarantee that it has only one owner.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C++11 you could add also a constructor that accepts an rvalue ref

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(T&& def_val) : default_val(new T(std::move(def_val))) {}
  MyClass::MyClass(const T& def_val) : default_val(new T(def_val)) {}
private:
  std::unique_ptr<T> default_val;
};
```

now you accept both const ref, generating a copy, or temporaries

Comment: You forgot to allocate an object in the `T&&` constructor.

Comment: (Edited to allocate the object in the `T&&` constructor). N.B. saying "If you're using C++11" is a bit redundant in a question about `unique_ptr`, which is also tagged [tag:c++11]